# No Module Named 'yfinance'

Tags: python, module, pip

I've recently been trying to follow a Data Science Project course online to get more accustomed to projects. I have three import statements right now, and I've tried basically every variation of pip install in both the Python terminal and my CPU terminal. However, I still get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yfinance'.
```

I've looked online for solutions, but I can't find any that address this problem. Any ideas as to what this could be?

```py
import yfinance as yf
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: Have you tried using a conda environment?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @CaptAngryEyes I'm on Mac

Comment: @JoshBone I'm not quite sure how I could do that. Could you please elaborate a bit? New to CS projects in general.

Comment: @roboticgrain sure, they have some pretty good instructions on the anaconda website. I highly recommend learning this if you plan on doing python projects in the future. https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Answer (score 1):

I had to run the following command:

```
python3 -m pip install yfinance
```

The -m tells it to install the module.

Just make sure you are using right command for the version of python terminal you are using and do apt-get update.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've tried that already and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that but did not work for me April/2023. I did this instead;

```
!pip install -r requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt content base for yfinance. Content:

```
numpy
panda
requests
lxml
```

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Yes, better yfinance not problem is gone, now it complaints at another library but yfinance problem is gone.)